# Conference Announcement Poster

Tags: posters

I am creating a conference announcement poster which can be downloaded [here](http://www.devio.us/~ppunosevac/cdynsys/uploads/Main/poster.pdf). The poster is not finished yet. I need to add list of invited speakers, information about registration, and NSF grant info which we got to pay for expenses.

There are people on this forum who know infinitely more about TeX, typography and creating posters than me. Could you kindly tell me your opinion about what I have done so far, share some of your own samples or direct me to possible templates?

I actually have a very nice template of conference poster but it is ill suited for conference announcement. I am just afraid that what I have done so far doesn't look professionally. On the top of it the background image is apparently cut due to my
incompetence. The source code is available [here](http://spots.aug.edu/ppunosev/poster.tex).

[image]

Comment: Can you also include with what mechanism you did this so far? Is it `beamerposter`,`a0poster` or just a flyer etc.? Also which part bothers you the most? As you might imagine, the question, as it is, doesn't give a way for a valid answer.

Comment: I used a0poster. I just uploaded source file to http://spots.aug.edu/ppunosev/poster.tex as well as Makefile http://spots.aug.edu/ppunosev/Makefile. If you make it, it will work but it will complain about missing pictures.

Comment: I'd use `$\langle\text{\url{ppunosev@aug.edu}}\rangle$` for the email address. The `<` and `>` don't look good. (Solution requires packages `amsmath` and `url`.)

Comment: One more suggestion. I'd letterspace the all-caps text. You may do this with the `microtype` package (use `\textls[50]{<text>}` to letterspace `<text>` with an extra 5% space.

Comment: Sorry, two more comments:-) First, I'd add a bit more vertical space after the date and between the names of the organisers. You can do this with `\\[<length>]`, where `<length>` is a proper LaTeX length. Next, I suggest you turn the URL into monospaced text. You may do this with `\url{http://www.devio.us/~ppunosevac/cdynsy/}. This solution requires the `url` package.

Comment: As a physicist, I question the images in the lower row: They make me think more of molecular or solid state physics than of dynamical systems (of course those systems can also be treated with dynamical system methods, but that's not the main way to treat them). So unless there's a good reason to have them in, I'd remove them or replace them by images more easily associated with dynamic systems.

Comment: I'd probably use sans-serif font, and even if I chose serif one, definitely not Computer Modern.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the poster still needs a little bit of a massage, both typographically as well as the copy. First the headline.

With a poster you want to get the attention of the reader. The headline has just a few seconds to attract attention in which the reader will decide to read further on or walk away. You can use what the advertising industry calls the ABC headline formula.

```
     A = Attention
     B = Benefits
     C = Creativity
 A+B+C = Headline
```

I think the headline needs to be turned around a bit. You need to decide if it is a symposium or conference and the announcement line can be omitted.

I would also remove the INVITED FROM "INVITED SPEAKERS". "Speakers" would suffice. You could also include photos of the speakers in a block below the poster. Images of people's faces will attract attention.

The colored graphic is distracting from the message, I will make it as transparent as possible and include it as a backdrop. All contact details I would put at the bottom, including the email, but I would not frame it in angle brackets. I would also remove the "more information" at the bottom and just have a `www.website.us/etc/etc.`, no need for the `http:\\` part.

And here is a very opinionated announcement. A bit of a modified headline. The reader goes nearer to have a look, we answer his questions, who is speaking, where, what is the benefit for him/her a little more details (its your 30 seconds elevator speech), who to contact where etc (can be below the text at the right, which I did not include). The graphics obviously and photos will need some work and attention, but if your selling point is the invited speakers, you should promote that.

[image][image]

**Update**

I added another variation to the theme, using a graphic rather than faces as the consensus appears to be that a Lorenz type of attractor  will be more likely to attract the attention of the group than faces (although I am sure that when you looked at the examples here, your attention was drawn to the faces first). Unless one does some A/B testing we will never know. One needs to really experiment with the copy once all the information is known. I used the [mathpazo](http://www.google.com.qa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mathpazo&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo&ei=1PdCT_CBF4i3rAeYy-jiBw&usg=AFQjCNE6eihQd8CUcrM0eV52N3MfKnKcLg&sig2=3Zm67ZZEr1SCOVsj-cjncQ) font
at 65pt and the soul package for spacing out. One should also print the poster and experiment with sizes. I would stick to my guns and not have any text on the graphics.

Schmendrich's ideas are also good especially the qr-code, you should try and incorporate it in the final version.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathpazo,xcolor}
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,soul,lipsum}
\parindent0pt
\def\lorem{\leavevmode Fusce adipiscing justo nec ante. Nullam in enim.
 Pellentesque felis orci, sagittis ac, malesuada et, facilisis in,
 ligula. Nunc non magna sit amet mi aliquam dictum. In mi. Curabitur
 sollicitudin justo sed quam et quadd. \par}
\makeatletter
\def\HUGE{\@setfontsize\HUGE{65}{90}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\raggedbottom
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
\sffamily
\centering
\HUGE{\bf SYMPOSIUM}\\

\LARGE{\textbf{\so{CAROLINA DYNAMICS GROUP}}}\\

\Large{\textbf{\so{CLEMSON UNIVERSITY}}}\\
%\large{\textbf{APRIL 5, 2012}}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
\normalsize
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{lorenzattractor01}

\textbf{PRESENTED BY THE CAROLINA DYNAMICAL \\ SYSTEMS GROUP}. Some more text here to fill the space. You need to get the reader to stop and read a bit more. Some more text here to fill the space. \par 
\rule{0pt}{32pt}
\end{minipage}\hspace{5pt}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.37\textwidth}
\textbf{\large INVITED SPEAKERS}\par

{\leavevmode \raggedright
Dr Liang Foo\\
Dr Berry Ling\\
Dr Zezsko Petrovick \\
Dr A Berchowitz\\
\par{}
}

\medskip

\large{\textbf{VENUE}}

The symposium will take place at Clemson University.

\medskip

{\large\raggedright
{\textbf{DYNAMICAL SYSTEMS}}
\par
}
\normalsize
\smallskip

\lorem\lorem\lorem

\medskip
\textbf{\large ORGANIZERS}\par
Martin Schmoll, Clemson University\\
Predrag Punosevac, Augusta State \\
University
\medskip

\textbf{\large CONTACT }\par

Predrag Punosevac, Augusta State\\
University
\textcolor{blue}{email@mail.com}

\rule{0pt}{78pt}
\end{minipage}
\vspace*{-70pt}

\HUGE{\bf APRIL 5 $\cdot$  2012}\\
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, some conferences distinguish between invited speakers (those being asked to give a presentation, and often are given more time for it than others) and other speakers (who asked for being able to give a talk and were accepted). If this conference does, the "invited" is not superfluous, but actually required.

Comment: @celtschk Sure they do, but is not a headline to get the attention of the reader. I would add it in the text on the left of the image I uploaded.

Comment: Actually, for me your poster suggestion does not look as if it were for a *scientific* conference. Indeed, I'd probably personally classify the poster as irrelevant before finding out. Remember, an announcement need not only attract initial attention, it must also immediately communicate that it may be relevant to *you*.

Comment: @celtschk This can be achieved with the choice of the photos. If Dr. Foos photo is in the poster and you know him as an authority this will answer both your points. The poster I showed, as I said is opinionated, it's not a finished product but just a demo. On a final one I would spent more time to make it relevant and experiment with the fonts and the heading, but maybe you can post your ideas?

Comment: Well, if I look at the original poster suggestion, the dominant thing is a picture which I, as physicist, immediately recognize as related to dynamical systems. Even if I know the speakers (however I often know important people only by name, not by face), many people are in several specialized fields (e.g. the same person may well be in a conference about quantum information or in a conference about fundamentals of physics, although they are different fields. And if it's a field which I'm newly interested in, but never worked in, I may not even know the important people of the field at all.

Comment: @celtschk: Scientific look does not mean to look bad. See, how Yiannis achieved a clean look: grouping the information, adjusting the text instead of centering it (I don't like the Title). You got the idea. If you want, replace the picture Yiannis used with the picture Predag used and you'll have an more scientific look. Or use Predags pic as a background image (with high opacity).

Comment: @schmendrich: I didn't want to imply that it has to look bad. However I *did* want to imply that when while trying to make it look good you  make it not look *relevant* then the result is worse even if it looks better. One of Yiannis' points was that the colored graphics was distracting from the message. My point was that the colored graphics very much *contains* a big part of the message.

Comment: @celtschk: I'm with you at this point. But the text shouldn't vanish behind the colors of the picture. I found Predag's example hard to read. I couldn't see all the information in "one view".

Comment: @schmendrich I will post another draft this evening, with a scientific picture on the left and the speaker photos at the bottom for comparison.

Comment: Good information about creating flyers and so on are in "The Non-Designer's Design Book" by Robin Williams (German book title "Design und Typografie für Dich"). Williams gives some rules to design such things.

Comment: The second version is much better. I especially like the fact that the date is now large. I didn't think of it, but in hindsight it seems obvious that the date belongs to the most important information. The only thing which I dislike (but that may be personal taste) is that the image on the left is so much higher than wide. I'd make it a bit shorter vertically. Maybe below it would be the best place to put more detailed information of the subjects covered (so that there's a logical grouping: left about the physics contents, right the non-physics aspects (speakers, location, contact, etc.).

Comment: Would you make the source code available?

Comment: @Marko Please see added MWE and  https://github.com/yannisl/MWE/blob/master/LorenzAttractor01.jpg for the image

Answer (score 7):

Why do you center some text? If you can't say why, you shouldn't center
it. Use raggedright instead. It will give the poster a cleaner look ("Because it is a title" is not a reason to center text)

Are the black pictures at the bottom really needed? Delete them, save whitespace. This will give also a cleaner more organized look.

Is the word ORGANIZERS more important than the names after it (why the capitals)?
BTW: Why do you name the organizers at the poster? Is it important to the announcement? Why not name them at the conference instead of the poster (I go by me: I'm interested in the conference; I don't care who organized it. So I don't need the information at the poster.)

No need for the "more information" text. The website's name is enough. Use the saved space to place a qr-code with the link to the website. (At the website should be MORE information ;)

Comment: +1 for the point on capitals (perhaps small caps instead?) and for QR-code, which I consider hip as well `:)`. You could use http://goqr.me/.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to post a second iteration of the poster and two summarize some of the most useful comments.

Here is the poster with the look which I like better but without the content.

[image]

As you can see it is still at works but I made some progress. I like the look and the feel of the header and the footer. I think that the font size is more or less OK but I am not sure if you could suggest me a better font. The font spacing mentioned by Marc van Dongen is bad. I could not use microtype package as it requires pdflatex which is not the usual part of my TeX work flow. I just got alternative **soul** package to work with my working copy. I incorporated few of his suggestions regarding e-mail address and url.

Yiannis Lazarides made all sorts of great comments. As you can see the top of the poster is completely inspired by his design. Yiannis, I would really appreciate your comments on the font, spacing and anything you can think of in the header. However as correctly pointed by celtschk human faces have no business on the poster due to the fact that the face of even most famous scientists my not be recognizable immediately even to the experts in the field. As correctly observer by celtschk the background picture is there to give you an idea what is conference about. I think I will try to find even lighter picture for the background. The pictures on the bottom serve the same purpose. I will try to put just lighter picture. Yiannis also got right that the names of the people are more important than their roles. I should use bigger font for names and smaller for the role. That is still not fixed but I will. Actually whole central section is now messed up.

As of "Invited Speakers" vs "Speakers" issue, being an Invited Speaker is a very special category and it is used as a major advertising tool. I am still missing info about NSF grant (it will come with mandatory logo) and pretty much the central content of the poster. Putting the name of organizers is very common too. I will probably edit this post several times during in-coming days but I would like to express my deepest appreciation for this most useful community.

Comment: With the new picture going over the whole background, the text is very hard to read. On the previous iteration, the picture was mainly on the right side, and only few, very bright parts of it on the left. In the original iteration, there was space for text on the left (which was mostly white, and only had a bright yellow part extending to the left). You should avoid putting the text over the image. BTW, I still don't understand how the images at the bottom are supposed to hint at dynamic systems.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks for the input. The pictures on the bottom are Costa Surface and they are related to the theory of billiards. That is indeed not a common knowledge.

Comment: celtschk is right, it is almost impossible to read the text over the picture. The text needs more contrast to the background. What about using a white transparent box for the text. You'll get more contrast. But maybe this will look "less serious".

Comment: @PredragPunosevac Thanks for your kind words. Please see my updated draft. Good luck with the Conference, it's a lot of hard work.