# What's the best option for creating a LaTeX poster?

Tags: document-classes, beamerposter, posters

I'm currently looking for a way to produce a poster using LaTeX.

I found enough answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex) on what are the possible ways to do it.

Though, there is no way to compare them and find the best option for making a poster. Plus some templates on the other topic aren't available anymore.

I have a few constrains for this :

- I have lots of figures
- It has to be a A0 format
- It's gonna contain some math formulas
- As a new user for LaTeX, I cannot handle very heavy codes yet, so if it could be an "easy" code in terms of manipulability of the blocks, of the colors, figures, etc... it would be better

I know the other topic talked about solutions like the package `beamer poster` with the `beamer` class, the `baposter` package and the `fancytikzposter` package, but what are the advantages and drawbacks of each one ?

And which solution is the best in my case ?

Comment: Related: [What can you tell me about poster design and typography in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45213/5764)

Comment: Maybe can also find http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41220/963 useful

Comment: is there a place where one can get hold of fancytikzposter? all links seem to be dead. google mainly leads to stackexchange

Comment: There : http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html

Comment: thank you for bringing tikzfancyposter up in the first place